# Read methods of class and store pathname of webservices in arraylist

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try
        {

            for(int i = 0; i < Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods().length; i++)
            {
                if(Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()[i].getParameters().length > 0 && 
                   Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()[i].getParameters()[0].getType().getSimpleName().equals("String") &&
                   Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()[i].getReturnType().getSimpleName().equals("String"))
                {

                        String app = Vtiger_Services.class.getDeclaredMethods()[i].getName();
                        list.add(app);
                        //se non sono uguali li aggiungo
                        con.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO Services (Name) VALUES ('"+ Vtiger_Services.class.getDeclaredMethods()[i].getName()+"')");//popolo la tabella services
                    }
                }

            }

            System.out.println(list);
        }
```

My class Vtiger services contains web services of application, i want to get the name and pathname of every web services present in my class

in this way I can get everyone's name but I can't memorize the pathname in an arraylist

```
String app = Vtiger_Services.class.getDeclaredMethods()[i].getName();
```

In variable app i want to store the pathname of every webservices

class Vtiger_services:

```
public class Vtiger_Services{ `@Path("getCustomer/{code : .+}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getCustomer(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @PathParam("code") int code) // il codice cliente è un intero
{
    if (token.equalsIgnoreCase(this.token)) {
        String sql = "select .......";
        // System.out.println(sql);
        Database db = new Database();
        String json = db.executeQueryTOJSON(sql);
        // System.out.println(json);
        return json;
    } else
        return "{\"error\":\"bad token provided or customer code\"}";
}
```

I want to get the Path of the method getCustomer and store the string in arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the technology/framework you are using to expose your services using HTTP as an endpoint, mapped to a URL path, I cannot answer your question. I'll try give a general direction though:

You will have to either implement the URL path mapping yourself to construct the path using the method name or you need to gain access to your web service frameworks mapping state to extract the URL path from there.

Java reflections are expensive/slow, so you should call the following methods only once, assigning the return value into a variable and use the variable afterwards(Refactor->extract variable) Edit: see jacq_42 answer for a partial implementation:

```
Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()
Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()[i].getParameters()
```

If the code you are writing is supposed to run periodically, you might want to replace your insert statement with a something that inserts or updates. Later on, you will most likely need to delete no longer existing web service entries (someone removed a method from the Vtiger_Services class) as well.

Don't ever create SQL statements using string concatenation, use parameterized statements( https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet ). In your example, it is not user input you are appending to the query, so the security risk is not there. And since a method name will most likely never contain a single quote, you'll be fine with quoting too, so in theory, you could build your statement like that and be fine and safe. But that will not be the case all the time and you will eventually build something vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. In case you are interested, it is listed in the top 10 security risks of web applications:https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

I hope that helps on your journey :)

Edit:
Since you need the value of the @Path annotation, you should be able to obtain the path by using getAnnotation:

```
Path annotation = method.getAnnotation(Path.class)
```

The `annotation` reference should provide you with a method to obtain the path.

And you should seriously check out SQL injection attacks, since

```
String sql = "select .......";
...
String json = db.executeQueryTOJSON(sql);
```

looks pretty dangerous to me.

Comment: thanks but i want to get the path of every methods not only the name

Comment: can you please provide a snippet of a method if that `Vtiger_Services` class?

Comment: I can read the xml and then get the path of every web services?

Comment: No, I didn't even mention XML. I said, that you can retrieve the annotations, these are the things with the @ sign in front, using reflection from a method the same way you can get the methods name. The annotation Path holds a string value for the path. So if you obtain the path annotation from your method, you can ask the obtained instance for its value, which will be the path string you are looking for.

Comment: can you make me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an error or exception? I can write the names of methods to a list:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods().length; i++) {
            Method method = Vtiger_Services.class.getMethods()[i];
            if (method.getParameters().length > 0
                    && method.getParameters()[0].getType().getSimpleName().equals("String")
                    && method.getReturnType().getSimpleName().equals("String")) {
                String methodName = Vtiger_Services.class.getDeclaredMethods()[i].getName();
                list.add(methodName);
                String statement = "INSERT INTO Services (Name) VALUES ('" + methodName + "')";
                System.out.println(statement);
                // se non sono uguali li aggiungo
                // con.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO Services (Name) VALUES ('"+ Vtiger_Services.class.getDeclaredMethods()[i].getName()+"')");//popolo la
                // tabella services
            }
        }
    } finally {
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

With a Vtiger_Services class:

```
class Vtiger_Services {

    public void method1() {
    }

    public String method2(String val) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I just wrote the statement for persisting the method names into a string.
I got the output:

```
INSERT INTO Services (Name) VALUES ('method2')
[method2]
```

Comment: I want to get all the path of every methods.. not only che name

Comment: example : searchSottoGruppo/{sigcos : .+}/{codgru : .+}/{codsgr : .+}/{dessgr : .+}

Comment: with function getName,I get only searchSottoGruppo

Comment: Can you post an example of your Vtiger_Services class?